# GParted live graphical mode not working

Tags: video, graphics, gparted

I want to run GParted live 1.0.0.3 on a laptop with both an integrated and discrete graphic card.
I managed to start GParted using the "vga=normal" boot option, but X refuses to start either if select the default configuration or if I run "Forcevideo" selecting either the "vesa" or "nv" options.
In any case the screen shows "Debian GNU/Linux 10 debian tty1" from which I'm not able to run any command.
Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

- disable the discrete graphics via BIOS or unplug the card from the motherboard(if not embedded obviously) and give it a go
- try with an older release, 0.25, 0.27 but this time i686 version (if you already tried with the amd64 or vice versa)
- add ”gl-debug” as a boot parameter and try starting the X interface manually, save the error and compare with different releases, post it back here
- must it be gparted live? this one has also gparted and many more: http://www.system-rescue-cd.org